# Can immediate values be used as segement selectors

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memory-segmentation

The context of this problem is that I am using 64 bit address space on an Intel processor.

I know that in X64 only gs and fs segment registers are available. All other segment bases are set to 0.

Since the number of segment registers are limited, can I use a number directly to index into the GDT instead?

Like

```
movq    0x12:Address, %rax
```

instead of

```
movq    %gs:Address, %rax
```

Comment: Not with a `mov`. `jmp` and `call` far instructions have special encoding for immediate values for segment and offset in 32-bit mode. In 32-bit code you can do something like `jmp $0x08, $jmplabel`

Comment: The encoding in my first comment is invalid in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Okay, so in 32 bit mode with use of such an instruction (jmp or call), will the cs be updated to the new segment selector?

Comment: Yes, in my example `jmp $0x08, $jmplabel` would set _CS_ to segment selector 0x08 and EIP to the offset of `jmplabel` .

Comment: @MichaelPetch. Okay thanks for clearing the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You have to load a segment selector into a segment register before being able to use it in a memory operand. Furthermore, of course all six of `cs`, `ds`, `es`, and `ss` are still available, what is not are segment offsets and limits except for `fs` and `gs` using a special mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is:

How would you expect that an instruction `movq 0x12:Address, %rax` works?

In 32-bit protected mode the expected behaviour is clear: If such an instruction existed it should work the same way `movl %fs:Address, %eax` behaves when `%fs` is `0x12`.

But how about 64-bit mode?

My information is from an older AMD CPU manual so it might not be true for the latest CPUs.

However as far as I understood that manual correctly the `%fs:` and `%gs:` prefixes do **NOT** use the `%fs` and `%gs` registers in 64-bit mode but they use the special registers `FS.base` and `GS.base`.

The contents of the `%fs` and `%gs` registers are ignored the same way the content of the `%ds` register is ignored in a "regular" operation.

If your question is:

**"Which instruction behaves the same way `movq %fs:Address, %rax` would behave if `%fs` contained a value of `0x12`?"**

The answer is simple: `movq %fs:Address, %rax`.

... because the `%fs` register is not used by this instruction at all!

If your question is:

**"Which instruction behaves the same way `movq %fs:Address, %rax` would behave if `FS.base` contained a value of `MyFsBase`?"**

The answer is also simple: `movq (Address+MyFsBase), %rax`

... because `%fs:Address` actually means: `(Address+FS.base)`.